# Why not $O(n^{\log_ba})$ for case 1 of the Master Theorem instead of $O(n^{(\log_ba) - \epsilon})$?

Tags: big-o-notation, master-theorem

Someone who was explaining to me the master theorem said that for the case 1, we compare the $n^{\log_b(a)}$ and $f(n)$. If the growth rate of $n^{\log_b(a)}$ is greater than the growth rate of $f(n)$ then we subtract an epsilon to have this equality:
$$f(n) = O(n^{(\log_ba) - \epsilon})$$

My question is, doesn't the notation $O$ say that $n^{\log_ba}$ is the upper bound of the $f(n)$? So why don't we just write $$f(n) = O(n^{\log_ba})$$

Comment: The first statement ist stronger. Case 1 of the Master Theorem only applies if $f$ is *significantly* (i.e. by an order of $n^\varepsilon$) smaller than $n^{\log_b a}$.

Comment: @ttnick I still don't get it.

Comment: Its because $O(n^{(log_ba) - \epsilon})$ is not the same as  $O(n^{log_ba})$

Comment: You could write $f(n)=o(n^{\log_ba})$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That might be misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

Suppose we have a positive function $T(n)$ such that

$$T(n) = a \cdot T\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + f(n)$$

with $a \geq 1, b > 1$. You are referring to case $1$ of [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):

$\qquad$ If $f \in O( n^{\log_b (a) - \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then $T \in \Theta\left( n^{\log_b a} \right)$.

(There are various versions of the master theorem. There is not much variation on the case $1$, though.)

##### Why don't we just write $f(n) = O(n^{\log_ba})$ as the antecedent for case $1$?

Because we cannot.

For example, consider $T(n)=2T(\frac n2)+n$.
So $a=2$, $b=2$, $\log_ba=1$, $f(n)=n=O(n^1)$. However, $T(n)\not\in\Theta(n^1)$.

In fact, $T(n)\in \Theta(n\log n)$. This $T(n)$ belongs to the situation with $a=b=2, k=0$ of the case $2$ of the master theorem:

$\qquad$ If $f \in \Theta( n^{\log_b a} \log^{k} n)$ for some $k \geq 0$, then $T(n)\in \Theta( n^{\log_b a} \log^{k+1} n)$.

##### Can we just write $f(n)=o(n^{\log_ba})$ as the antecedent for case $1$?

No, we cannot either.

For example, consider $T(n)=2T(\frac n2)+n/\log n$.
So $a=2$, $b=2$, $\log_ba=1$, $f(n)=n/\log n\in o(n^1)$. However, $T(n)\not\in\Theta(n^1)$.

In fact, applying [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), we have $T(n)\in \Theta(n\log\log n)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705278/580448) for an easy explanation why $T(n)\in \Theta(n\log\log n)$.

##### So, $O(n^{(\log_ba) - \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

"Case $1$ of the master theorem only applies if $f(n)$ is significantly (i.e. by an order of $n^ε$ for some $\epsilon>0$) smaller than $n^{\log_ba}$", as ttnick [remarked](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154368/#comment324523_154368).